# Question about privacy advice on different online service providers - is it too opinion based?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question

I have been trying **not** to upload photos to cloud service providers such as Amazon, Google or Apple in the past - primarily due to privacy concerns. However, keeping them accessible to the family is tricky and I was wondering if I could ask about which alternative / online service would be recommended to maintain a reasonable amount of privacy, while still being able to access and share our personal photos.

Is this question too opinion-based? Is there anywhere else (e.g. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) where I could possibly ask about this or is this just not a question suitable for stackexchange?

Comment: Off topic here - and probably on softwarerecs too.

Comment: Chris - this is entirely opinion based. You can look at privacy concerns with any file sharing service, and can sort them any way you see fit. For some people, Amazon is fine. For others it isn't.

Comment: On the other hand, you could ask about what are the risk factors, and how privacy is actually affected using such services, and how to protect your privacy. If you make it more generic (and not "which service should I use") it becomes a much better question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the directions everyone.