# When a comment answers a question, should the thread be left there or should an answer based on the comment be written?

Tags: discussion, questions, answering

See [this question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/question-about-privacy-advice-on-different-online-service-providers-is-it-too) in meta itself to see a simple example:

Sure the comments answered it, but it could do with an actual answer in place to make it so that it is resolved and people who have the same question can find it easier. A really cool feature would be the ability to mark the comment as the answer maybe?

Or am I just barking up the wrong tree here and I should let sleeping dogs lie?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that's a bad example because the correct answer is, "close the question as off-topic" ;)

If there's a useful answer that someone has already submitted as a comment, that's a *great opportunity* for a low-rep user to gain some easy rep by writing up a complete answer with some supporting text and links.

So if this is happening a lot, the real problem is that there aren't enough ambitious new users.

Comment: +1 I do this all the time - but make sure to give credit for the idea, I always start my answer with "Expanding on what @drewbenn said in comments..."

Comment: I also often leave a comment-on-the-comment to the effect of "@drewbenn, if you turn that into an answer, I'll +1 it :-)"

Comment: I thought this was discouraged as it would be "stealing" other people's points, but it's definitely a good idea.  There are a LOT of 'unanswered' questions where the answer is just in the comments.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree with you @drewbenn, I'm just saying that's what other people said about it.  I'm more than happy to provide an answer based of comments if nobody else has.